# ¿como hacer push array dentro de un objeto que esta en un array?

Tags: javascript, json, array

estoy tratando de crear un JSON y necesito hacer lo siguiente:

```
var arreglo = [];

var sumar = () => {
    var id = arreglo.length + 1; 

    arreglo.push({id: id});

    console.log('Arreglo', arreglo)
};

sumar();
```

como Resultado imprime: `Arreglo [ { id: 1 } ]`.

Supongamos que ejecuto la función dos veces para el ejemplo y
tendría este array: `[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]`.

Lo que quiero conseguir es poder agregar un arreglo a donde esta el `id: 1`

o al `id` que se valla generando, logrado que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
[ {"id": 1 ,
"preguntas":[{
    "idp":1,
    "preg": "¿como estás?"
},{
   "idp":2,
   "preg": "it is important make my laptop?"
}]}, 
  { "id": 2,
"preguntas":[{
    "idp":1,
    "preg": "¿como estás?"
},{
    "idp":2,
    "preg": "it is important make my laptop?"
}]}
```

]

Se que primero que llenar otro arreglo:

```
  var sumarAobj = () => {
  var id = arregloInterno.length + 1;

  arregloInterno.push({
  id: id,
  pregunta: '¿como estás?'
});

...
```

};

¿Como debería continuar? probé con push y splice pero no quiere.

Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo lograste hacer? Y te faltó el lenguaje en las etiquetas, supongo que es javascript.

Comment: Aún estoy en eso recorriendo for al arreglo global encontrando el id y ver cómo hacer push xd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si entendi bien, lo que quieres es tener un array de objetos, donde cada objeto tenga un array y a ese array agregar elementos.

Accede al indece de cada elemento en el array y luego a la propiedad que tiene el array y le agregas con `.push()`:

```js
var data = [];
data.push({id:1, preguntas: []});
data[0].preguntas.push({idp: 1, preg: "¿Que dia es hoy?"});
data[0].preguntas.push({idp: 2, preg: "¿Esta frio fuera?"});

console.log(data);
```

Aqui un ejemplo agreando elementos con un for:

```js
var data = [];
   for(var i = 3; i < 10; i++)
   {
   
         data.push({ id:i, preg:[] });
         data[data.length-1].preg.push( {pid: i, preg: "Aqui pregunta" });
   }

console.log(data);
```

Comment: oh como no se me ocurrió antes, gracias.